# How to remove decimal digit from result in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove digit after decimal how to solve it?

My query is:

```
SELECT city_name,
       Assignedto,
       COUNT(Assignedto) AS TC,
       CONCAT(count(CASE
                        WHEN STATUS = 'CLOSED' THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END) * 100 / count(1), '%') AS SC,
       CONCAT(count(CASE
                        WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING' THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END) * 100 / count(1), '%') AS PC,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60 AS WH,
       (154440-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60) AS VH,
       CONCAT(COUNT(Feedback_Rate)/COUNT(Assignedto)*100,'%') AS Feed_Percent,
       SUM(Feedback_Rate)/(count(Feedback_Rate)*5)*5 AS AVG_Feedback
FROM `it_service_ticket`
INNER JOIN `it_problem`ON `it_service_ticket`.`it_problem_id`=`it_problem`.`it_problem_id`
INNER JOIN `city_master` ON `it_service_ticket`.cityid=`city_master`.city_id
WHERE `it_service_ticket`.`xetr` BETWEEN '2016-04-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2017-02-28 12:00:00 PM'
GROUP BY Assignedto
ORDER BY city_name ASC;
```

Output

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|       City_Name         |       AssigneeTo        |  TC   |    SC      |   PC     |    WH      |     VH       | Feedback  | Average |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
| Ahmedabad               | mahesh.patel@corp.in  |  297  | 100.0000%  | 0.0000%  |  147.0667  | 154292.9333  | 43.4343%  |  4.4031 |
```

| Ahmedabad               | mahesh.patel@corp.in  |  297  | 100.0000%  | 0.0000%  |  147.0667  | 154292.9333  | 43.4343%  |  4.4031 |

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. If you want to round off decimal places, use `ROUND(yourColumn,0)` function.

   So `13.78` will become `14`
2. If you want to get rid of decimal places, user `FLOOR(yourColumn)`

   So `13.78` will become `13`

So for example

`SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60 AS WH`

should be changed to

`ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60,0) AS WH`

Edit: This would take care of your `%`.

```
CONCAT(
        ROUND(count(CASE
            WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END) * 100 / count(1),0)
        , '%') AS PC
```

Do the same for all the columns you need to remove decimal places.

Comment: CONCAT(count(CASE
                        WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING' THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END) * 100 / count(1), '%') AS PC,

Comment: In this case I want to show 100 % in output how to solve

Answer (score 5):

You Should Use TRUNCATE() in Mysql for Example

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(525.668545, 3) -- 525.668
```